# How do I get an object in the "many" part from a One-To-Many unidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I don't know how to exactly express what I'm looking for, so I'll explain what I have and then what I'm trying to do.

I have a Class model, which has 2 classes with a One-To-Many unidirectional relationship.

```
public class TaxType extends Entity implements java.io.Serializable {
    //stuff
    private Set<TaxTypeAttribute> listTaxTypeAttribute = new HashSet<>(0);
}
public class TaxTypeAttribute extends Entity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String attributeName;
    //stuff, but no reference to TaxType
}
```

Entity Class is like a primary key standard, we call it "OID design pattern", but no clue if it's like that in english.

```
public class Entity {
    private String oid;
    //constructor, get and set
}
```

On the mapping, it goes like this:

```
<class name="entity.TaxType" table="taxttype" catalog="tax_type" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="oid" type="string">
        <column name="OIDtt" length="50" />
        <generator class="uuid2" />
    </id>        
    <set name="listAtributoTipoImpuesto">
        <key column="OIDtt" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="entidades.AtributoTipoImpuesto" />
    </set>
</class>
<!-- two separated files, this is just for showing -->
<class name="entity.TaxTypeAttribute" table="taxtypeattribute" catalog="tax_type" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="oid" type="string">
        <column name="OIDtta" length="50" />
        <generator class="uuid2" />
    </id>
    <property name="attributeName" type="string">
        <column name="attributeName" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
</class>
```

In one step of the program, I have a TaxType and the `attributeName` from a TaxTypeAttribute, but I need to get the full TaxTypeAttribute. I'm making querys through Criteria API. I could do `taxType.getListTaxTypeAttribute();` and do a loop until I find the object, but I would like to know if there's a way to do it using some Hibernate querys.

I've tried doing `taxType.getOid();` and then using that and the `attributeName` but it throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: OIDtt of: entity.TaxTypeAttribute
```

Any clues? Thanks you, and excuse me for my bad english

**EDIT:** In order to follow design patterns, we use this method to do SELECT querys: [Awful thing we use for querys](http://pastebin.com/aZiiMBZG).
The way I did it is this:

```
ArrayList<DTOCriteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<>();
DTOCriteria c1 = new DTOCriteria();
c1.setAttribute("OIDtt");
c1.setOperation("=");
c1.setValue(taxType.getOID());
criteriaList.add(c1);
ArrayList<Object> found = search("TaxTypeAttribute");
```

I could add another DTOCriteria if I want ("attributeName";"=";attributeName, for example), but if the former doesn't works it's kind of useless. I also tried (just because it's free) using "TaxType" as attribute and the TaxType object as a value, but didn't work either.

PS: the code works. I use it for other querys and works, it just doesn't work for this one, or I don't know how to make it work. May be you can't do that kind of search, I don't know.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the mapping.Recheck the pojo's and the column and table names.Also post your code where you have fired the query.

Comment: The mapping is fine, at least it works for every other Criteria query. This is the only one not working. I'm editing the post to add the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an HQL/JPQL perspective, you could write your query as:

```
SELECT tta FROM TaxType tt JOIN tt.listTaxTypeAttribute tta
 WHERE tt.oid = :oid
   AND tta.attributeName = :attributeName
```

This query will return you `TaxTypeAttribute` instances that match the specified criteria.  How you translate that into your query language is something which I cannot aid with.

Comment: I tried it and it works... sadly, we aren't allowed to use JOIN, but it seems it's the only way. I'll talk about it to my teachers. Thanks you!

Comment: What are you allowed to use?  Perhaps a back reference association?